# Nessus Vulnerability Scanner

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, nessus

My question is: can we use Nessus to perform a scan on a remote server? Or is it used only to perform scans on the local network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean "on a remote server" but very simply put: yes, you can - as long as you're authorized.

If your scenario is to scan server which lies outside of your local network (for example a different server belonging to your company, hosted somewhere else) Nessus is your choice.

If you mean you want to perform a scan from a remote server with Nessus, that's possible as well. Our company uses Nessus on a dedicated server for external scans.

But be warned - don't scan server which you're not authorized to.

I also believe trial version is only for non-commercial scans.

Happy scanning!

Comment: @JamalD Happy to help. Can you mark this thread as solved?

Comment: Using scanners with non-intrusive/destructive behaviour is not illegal (where i live), even if you do it without permission - as long as you do not harm/breach/intrude the system you are scanning.